# Can I move entire c# WinForms element to another different form or tab using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a form (new-form) and after using it for some time I want to move all it's element, methods and triggers to another form or tab (old-form).

I tried to copy past the trigger methods from new-form to old-form .e.g. TextChanged method.
I then tried to cut/paste an element, e.g. TextBox from new-form and paste in old-form however, the trigger methods were not pasted.

Is there a way I can copy all the element from new-form to old-form without loosing the triggers methods and other data?

I also tried to generate the triggers dynamically like this:

```
    wpLatMin1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(WpMinDigitChecker);
    wpLatMin1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(wpMin_TextChanged);
```

I define e.g. WpMinDigitChecker:

```
private void WpMinDigitChecker(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !e.KeyChar.Equals('.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

However, after testing the form, VS deletes the content of the methid and I am left with:

```
private void WpMinDigitChecker(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
}
```

why does it delete the content?

Comment: If that is not possible, or too complicated, can I copy a form element, in the same form and keep all it's triggers?
I use the same trigger method for similar elements.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. If you want to add more information, edit the question.

Comment: If you drag and drop within a form then nothing changes other than the location and possibly the parent. If you cut/copy and paste, even within the same form, the event handler registrations are not maintained.

Comment: I would just go outside VS and make a copy of the `Form.cs` and `Form.Designer.cs` fies, rename the class name in both files and then import into VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy and paste the controls and the code but there will be no connection between the controls and the event-handling methods if you do that. You need to select a control in the designer, open the *Properties* window, click the *Events* button and then select the appropriate method from the drop-down for all the required events.